# is it more performant to write one complicated shader or several different shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am just learning OpenGL, and I'm realizing that for more complex shader effects, there are basically two stategies that you can use to implement them. The first is to write one complicated vertex and fragment shader that accepts a number of different uniform variables from the main program, and decides what to do in the shader. Ex. if I want to make pixels in one context blue and in another context green, I might do in GLSL:

```
uniform int whichColor;
int main() {
    if (whichColor == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0,1.0,0,1.0);
    }
    else {
          gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,1.0,1.0);
    }
 }
```

and pass different ints to whichColor in my C++ drawing loop. Alternatively, I could just define two separate shader programs, one of which sets gl_FragColor to blue and the other to green, and simply load one or the other when it is time for me to draw a particular object in my OpenGL scene.

I can't seem find any information on which one of these strategies is better, though. I might expect the first strategy, putting all the complexity of what to render on the graphics card, to be more performant, but in the sorts of cases I'm thinking of deciding what to draw isn't a per-pixel calculation and doesn't benefit from parallelization. I don't really understand how the shader programs run on the graphics card and what the costs of linking and passing variables are, so I'm not sure that my intuition is actually correct here.

Comment: "Better" is a subjective question. It cannot be answered, so questions asking which is "better" aren't welcome on SO. At the very least, put some criteria on it. "Better" in what way?

Comment: By "better" I mean "in general faster" or perhaps "requires the least amount of transferring data between system and gfx card memory" or "closer to what professional OpenGL developers actually do". What's the cost of loading a new shader a bunch of times in the glut display function compared to the cost of writing one really complicated shader and passing data to it through uniforms constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked for answers on this topic a while ago, too. What I've gathered from a few different games and books is that you'd generally use different shaders.

You can compile all needed shader programs once and make every object-to-be-drawn switch to the required shader program:

```
void Draw(){

    glUseProgram(yourShaderProgram);

    glUniformX(yourUniformVariables);

    glDrawArrays(yourVAO);

}
```

What you do NOT want to do is load and link the shader program everytime you need it.

Rather, keep a list of all shader programs somewhere, or pass the program's id to each objects so they can make use of it.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you can at least use `#define`s to hold the combinatorial explosion of your shader source codes in reasonable limits.